# How do I make non-numbered chapters look right?

Tags: chapters, memoir

Someone was kind enough to help me make this chapter style:

```
 \documentclass[openany]{memoir} % redefine numbering
 \newcommand{\numtoword}[1]{\ifcase\value{chapter}?\or first \or
 second\else ?\fi}
 
 % c&p from memoir.cls's brotherton style \usepackage{xpatch}
 \makechapterstyle{matheson}{%   \xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
     {\printchaptername \chapternamenum \printchapternum}
     {\printchapternum \chapternamenum \printchaptername}
     {}
     {}   \chapterstyle{default}   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont
 \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\centering\large\MakeUppercase}
 \ifanappendix \thechapter \else
 \large\MakeUppercase{\numtoword{\value{chapter}}}\fi}
 
 \setlength{\beforechapskip}{\baselineskip}
 \setlength{\afterchapskip}{-10pt} } \chapterstyle{matheson}
 
 
 \begin{document} \chapter{} This looks as it should.
 
 \chapter*{Chapter with name} This certainly does not.
 
 \chapter{Chapter with another name} This is not too snappy either.
 \end{document}
```

It looks cool when I have just do `\chapter{}`:

[image: Chapter]

When I do `\chapter*{Chapter with name}` it's a different story:

[image: Chapter]

Same thing with `\chapter{Chapter with another name}`:

[image: Chapter]

Now, how do I get "CHAPTER WITH NAME" in the "FIRST CHAPTER"-style for the starred chapter? And how do I get "SECOND CHAPTER: CHAPTER WITH ANOTHER NAME" for the unstarred version? I don't need it right now, but for completion I think it would be nice to have.

Lastly, as you can see the spacing below the chapter heading is not done properly. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Do your numbered chapters have a title or not?

Comment: They do not. But I guess it should be an option for the style to be complete.